# How to evaluate a sum of rational expression containing $\sin$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How one can find the value of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{8\sin((2n-1)x)}{\pi (4(2n-1)-(2n-1)^3)}?$$

Wolfram $\alpha$ gave an ugly expression involving $i$ but I think one can simplify the expression as we sum only real numbers.

Comment: You could try to use trigonometric formulas for sum of angles and double angles.

Comment: You must resist the temptation to fall into sin.

Comment: The usual trick is to replace $\sin x$ with $e^{ix}$, then calculate the sum and look at the imaginary part. Have you tried this?